# IDs not prepended properly in composite container

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, composite-component

I have the problem that on an initial pageload the ids of elements inside the composite container are not prepended properly, which leads to "wrong" http-POSTs.

As an example

```
<h:form id="select">
    <tb:input id="selectPLZ" value="#{companys.selectedPLZ}">
    </tb:input>
</h:form>
```

tb:input

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="value" required="true"/>
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}" id="field">
    </h:inputText>
</composite:implementation>
```

On the initial page load, the input element has as it's id only the id of the composite container and it's own (for example: "j_idt93:field") but not the full id it should have ("select:j_idt93_field"), the id of the form is not prepended.

If I rerender the component or reload the page the id is correct again.

Any Idea to solve this problem?

Comment: What is `selectPLZ` good for ? It looks like you never use it.

Comment: That is just an example code not my original one, but the problem also arises if I just use this.